# Delphi 2009 startup error

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

When I click Delphi 2009 to start it shows me this error.

[image]

Comment: Now that's something you don't see every day... A few questions. Has it ever worked? Have you tried reïnstalling? Have you tried opening it without loading any 3th party tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [embarcadero forum message](https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=153641) discusses the same issue you are having.

> Does it occur when you run with the
>   -np switch?

Comment: when i used this command it works well "BDS.EXE -rtest" without quotes.

Comment: To me, that's an indication one of your installed components/tools is misbehaving. Essentially, by adding -rTest, you are using a blanc configuration (at least, that's my understanding of things).

Comment: Can you incrementally uninstall packages until you find the offending one?

Comment: Do you mean an entire reinstall of Windows or only Delphi?