# Error Starting Delphi When Debugging Design Time Package

Tags: delphi, debugging, package, delphi-2010

I've encountered a problem starting a second instance of Delphi 2010 for debugging a design time package. Under Project Options|Debugger, I use "C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\bin\bds.exe" as the host app with these parameters: "-pDelphi -nocache"

I get the following error message when I run the package:

[image]

If I continue, I get the following:

[image]

Then, if I continue, I get the following:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? This has always worked before. (I have repaired and uninstalled/reinstalled Delphi 2010.)

Comment: What is Z:\DelphiFPC\Shared\IDE\IDEHooks.pas?

Comment: Are you running any custom memory managers like fastMM? Have you installed any new packages recently? Does [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144199/delphi-2009-startup-error) solve your problems? Does your problem persist if you disable any code collaboration tools you might have installed?

Comment: @jachguate:I have no idea. I only have c: and d: drives on this machine.

Comment: @TildalWave: No new packages. No fastMM (unless D2010 installed it). However, tomorrow, I will try the thread you suggest and also disable any 3rd party tools.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have a debug build of DDevExtensions installed. This version verifies its GetProcAddress calls to show missing symbols if a debugger is attached. DDevExtensions tries to hook into bcbide140.bpl (C++Builder) but doesn't find the symbols because the BPL isn't loaded (`bds -pDelphi`).It should skip the hooking but due to the debug build and an attached debugger it runs into the assertion.

The reason for the debug build lies in the build script of DDevExtensions: `msbuild /p:Configuration=Release` instead of `msbuild /p:Config=Release`. (So thanks for "reporting" this so I can fix the build script).

Comment: Thanks, Andreas. I uninstalled DDevExtensions, and no longer get the errors. (But I will miss DDevExtensions. Your work is much appreciated by many of us.)

Comment: Version 2.7 will fix this. A development snapshot is available: http://andy.jgknet.de/ddev/dev