# jvPluginSystem not installable in delphi 10 Seattle

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle, jvcl

I installed JCL/JVCL in my Delphi 10 Seattle, first from getit, later manually. I cannot install the jvPluginSystem design package. All packages work well but this design package produces an EAccessVialolation in jclDeveloperTools. I double checked for multiple instances of dcu's and bpl's and also tried on a freshly baught Windows 10 Surface pro without any other Delphi versions. Same result. I also checked that unitversioning is off in JCL and JVCL and did a complete build of the packages.

I suspect that it came either with the latest Delphi Update 1 for Seattle or it is a Windows 10 related issue. Did anyone also experience this Problem?

I used Version 3.4.9 Complete Package (including JCL) from Sourceforge.

Comment: You can debug the IDE and find where this crashes. Are you familiar with the technique?  Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532835/error-starting-delphi-when-debugging-design-time-package

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was not aware of this and will try it today!

Comment: You can in some cases even launch delphi, wait for the crash, then attach the debugger, but usually it's better to attach before the exception or else start the ide. I plan to write a detailed tutorial on my Delphi Code MOnkey blog on this subject soon.

Comment: @Warren: Sounds great, looking Forward to reading this tutorial soon!

Comment: Solved my issue by reinstallation through getit. But I am interested in generally solving a Problem like this.

Comment: Check out this quick tutorial http://delphicodemonkey.blogspot.ca/2015/12/how-to-find-and-fix-problems-in-your.html